# I am looking for a fantasy story with 4 orphans raised on a mountain

Tags: story-identification

There are 2 books in the series, but they are orphans raised in a snow covered mountain.  After that they are working in a castle.  one child is killed while picking apples.  one child leaves to find where the dead child's spirit is said to live.  the girl becomes a powerful witch with 2 or 3 other sisters.

Comment: Can you describe the setting a bit more fully? Sword/Sorcery, Medieval? Do you recall any of the orphans names? Why did they move to the castle? Who was raising them? Did the mountain have a name? How was the child killed picking apples? What witchy powers did the girl develop?